# Speed up query when criteria requires large number of fields to be searched for values in in lists

Tags: sql-server

I'm working with some large health data tables (3B+ rows) and tasked with flagging and selecting rows based on lists of medical codes.

Consider a table EVENT

```
( id bigint
, edate date
, d1 char(5), d2 char(5), d3 char(5), d4 char(5), d5 char(5), d6 char(5), d7 char(5), d8 char(5), d9 char(5), d10 char(5)
, p1 char(5), p2 char(5), p3 char(5), p4 char(5), p5 char(5), p6 char(5), p7 char(5), p8 char(5), p9 char(5), p10 char(5)
, and many other fields
)
```

that has to be queried and have flags assigned as such

```
select * from 
(
 select ...
 , case when
    p1 in (x1, ... ,xN1) or ... or p10 in (x1, ... ,xN1) then 'Y' else 'N' end as X_FLAG
 , case when
    p1 in (y1, ... yN2) or ... or p10 in (y1, ... ,yN2) then 'Y' else 'N' end as Y_FLAG
 , case when
    d1 in (z1, ... ,zN3) or ... or p10 in (z1, ... ,zN3) then 'Y' else 'N' end as Z_FLAG
 , case when
    d1 in (q1, ... ,qN4) or ... or d10 in (q1, ... ,qN4) then 'Y' else 'N' end as Q_FLAG
...
 from EVENT
 where
...
) tagged
into FURTHER_STUDY
where X_FLAG='Y' or Y_FLAG='Y' or Z_FLAG='Y' or Q_FLAG='Y'
```

As the number of fields be searched and number of flags being assigned the query duration gets rapidly longer.

Are the better ways to formulate the query for speed ?
For example, do the OR's shortcut or would each long OR chain be better of as a larger CASE statement ?

Can/Should a procedure be used that scans row by row?

Answer (score 0):

If you do any kind of data manipulation on 3 billion rows at run time, especially with this many case statements the query will take its time to process the data.

After all 3 billon rows is not a small number. Also I hope you have these 3B rows in some sort of data warehouse not in an OLTP database.

I  think computed columns maybe a possible solution for this. Add these four columns for Flag_X, Y Z G etc and make them computed see if you get any performance gain.

An example of computed columns, similar to your requirement would be something like.....

### Table Schema

```
DECLARE @t TABLE 
 ( ID INT 
 , ID2 INT 
 , Flag_X AS (CASE WHEN ID IN (1,2) OR ID2 IN (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) PERSISTED
 , Flag_Y AS (CASE WHEN ID IN (2,3) OR ID2 IN (2,3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) PERSISTED)

INSERT INTO @t(ID , ID2) VALUES 
(1 , 1),
(3 , 1),
(3 , 3)
```

### Test

```
SELECT * FROM @t 

╔════╦═════╦════════╦════════╗
║ ID ║ ID2 ║ Flag_X ║ Flag_Y ║
╠════╬═════╬════════╬════════╣
║  1 ║   1 ║      1 ║      0 ║
║  3 ║   1 ║      1 ║      1 ║
║  3 ║   3 ║      0 ║      1 ║
╚════╩═════╩════════╩════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those rare cases where I may use several steps, rather than try to get it into a single statement.

But if I absolutely had to get this into a single statement, I'd look to put those flags into their own table, and then I'd join against that table rather than using `IN ()` clauses. This would simplify the query (no need to list out a potentially long list of selectors) and improve performance (the new flag table can have indexes and statistics that will help Sql Server produce the results).

What I would still *not* do is write a procedure or cursor to scan row by row. Sql Server can already do that if it needs to, and doing exactly that is likely contributing to why this becomes slow. When I say "several steps", I mean something more like one step for all of your XFlags, one step for all of your YFlags, etc.